# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu Not Closing On Click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

We have a single page responsive website that was built using OctoberCMS and everything seems to be working fine, minus one minor issue. The navbar has a dropdown menu that doesn't close automatically when you click or tap an item within it. On desktop, you have to click anywhere on the page for it to close and on mobile you need to click on the menu button again. Just looking for the right way to set this up. Here is the current code block and note that we are using bootstrap 3.3.1 on the site:

```html
<nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="{{ 'assets/images/logo.png'|theme }}" alt="logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="scroll active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="scroll dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button">Main Menu 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#1">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#2">Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#3">Section 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#main3">Main Menu 3</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#main4">Main Menu 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.container-->
</nav>
<!--/nav-->
```

When looking in the developer console I see the following error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js:21)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:4)
    at init.each (jquery.js:4)
    at Scroll (main.js:20)
    at main.js:5
    at dispatch (jquery.js:5)
    at v.handle (jquery.js:5)
```

And here is the scroll code from the main.js file:

```js
function Scroll() {
  var contentTop      =   [];
  var contentBottom   =   [];
  var winTop      =   $(window).scrollTop();
  var rangeTop    =   200;
  var rangeBottom =   500;
  $('.navbar-collapse').find('.scroll a').each(function(){
   contentTop.push( $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top);
   contentBottom.push( $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top + $( $(this).attr('href') ).height() );
  })
  $.each( contentTop, function(i){
   if ( winTop > contentTop[i] - rangeTop ){
    $('.navbar-collapse li.scroll')
    .removeClass('active')
    .eq(i).addClass('active');   
   }
  })
 };

 $('#tohash').on('click', function(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 5}, 1000);
  return false;
 });
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I know this is a minor version off from the bootstrap version you're using, but I'm able to click on the drop down and drop down items to close the menus. Here's a [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/cviX07Fv3T) that implements your code that you can take a look at.

Comment: did you include jquery? as bootstrap css depend on jquery for certain event

Comment: Yeah, I included jquery. I played around today a bit more an it looks like there is something funky going on with the js from the October CMS theme that we used. Going to post the error and the code that appears to be causing the issue above.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. The syntax error is arisen in `href="#"` . Try this code

```
<nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="{{ 'assets/images/logo.png'|theme }}" alt="logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="scroll active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="scroll dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button">Main Menu 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#1">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#2">Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#3">Section 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#main3">Main Menu 3</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#main4">Main Menu 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.container-->
</nav>
<!--/nav-->
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I did some more testing and am seeing an error in the developer console. I have added the error and the scroll code from the js file above.